# Pass a Previous Value to function MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, iteration, persistent

I have the following function:

```
y(t) = alpha*y(t-1) + beta*y(t-1) + delta
```

where alpha,beta, and delta are constants.

I am assuming that y(0) = 0. I'm trying to create a MATLAB function to represent y(t) using the persistent command. I pass 0 as the initial condition for y(t) when I call my function for the first time. I then use a for loop to update y(t) for 1000 iterations. For some reason my output for y(t), y_out, never changes in size and remains 0. I'm not sure why this is happening. How do I get y(t) to update iteratively as t increases?

```
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 0.3;
delta = 0.8;

y_out = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta,0);

for t=2:1:1000
    y_out = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta); 
end

function y_out = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta,varargin) % pass 0 to varargin as y(0) = 0 only the first time you call the function
 persistent y
 if nargin>3
     y = y + alpha*varargin{1} + beta*varargin{1} + delta
 end
 y_out = y;
end
```

Comment: You’re not doing any computations when `nargin==3`, you’re just outputting the previous value. Then, inside the loop, you want to assign into `y_out(t)`.

Comment: Do note that your function is identical to `(alpha + beta) * y(t-1) + delta`!

Comment: Ok. I changed y_out = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta); to y_out = y_out +  NARMA(alpha,beta,delta) in the for loop. I also changed y = y + alpha*varargin{1} + beta*varargin{1} + delta; to y = alpha*varargin{1} + beta*varargin{1} + delta. But now I get a y_out that is 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, ... meaning that the code is just adding delta each iteration. Why is each iteration updating y_out with alpha and beta according to my y(t) function? @CrisLuengo

Comment: As I said, you want to do `y_out(t) = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta);`. That way you assign the new value to a new array element every time.

Comment: If I do that do I have to initialize y_out to a predefined size before populating it within the for loop? If I don't I get this error: "Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side." @CrisLuengo

Comment: You don't need to initialize `y_out` to the final size, though it is more efficient if you do so. The problem is that `NARMA` is still returning an empty array. You need to fix that function first to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're complicating your program with the persistent variable. I would implement it this way:

```matlab
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 0.3;
delta = 0.8;

N = 100;
y_out = zeros(1, N);
y_out(1) = NARMA(0,alpha,beta,delta);
for t=2:N
    y_out(t) = NARMA(y_out(t-1),alpha,beta,delta);
end

function y_out = NARMA(y_in,alpha,beta,delta)
    y_out = alpha*y_in + beta*y_in + delta;
end
```

---

Because the function is now one line, you could instead use an anonymous function like so:

```matlab
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 0.3;
delta = 0.8;

NARMA = @(y_in) alpha*y_in + beta*y_in + delta;

N = 100;
y_out = zeros(1, N);
y_out(1) = NARMA(0);
for t=2:N
    y_out(t) = NARMA(y_out(t-1));
end
```

Note how the anonymous function (also called a lambda) captures the value of the variables `alpha`, `beta` and `delta` at the moment it's defined. We don't need to pass these in as function arguments, they've become part of the function.

---

If you insist on using a persistent variable, you could do it this way:

```matlab
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 0.3;
delta = 0.8;

N = 100;
y_out = zeros(1, N);
y_out(1) = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta,true);
for t=2:N
    y_out(t) = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta);
end

function y_out = NARMA(alpha,beta,delta,first_call)
    % Set first_call to true only the first time you call the function
    persistent y
    if nargin>3 && first_call
        y = 0;
    end
    y = alpha*y + beta*y + delta;
    y_out = y;
end
```

Comment: These are both excellent options Bravo. @CrisLuengo